# Containerizing .Net 6 Web Api using Docker

Tags: docker, containers, devops, nuget-package, orchestration

I am containerizing the .NET 6 Web API which includes custom NuGet feeds. The docker build is successful but when I do run the docker container it sends an empty response.

Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["test.OrganizationService.csproj", "./"]
COPY ./nuget.config .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "test.OrganizationService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "test.OrganizationService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.OrganizationService.dll"]
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Using the following documentation for Managing NuGet Credentials in Docker

[Managing NuGet Credentials in Docker Scenarios](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md)

Comment: Why do you think that your issue has something to do with your nuget feed?

Comment: Please add the docker command you use to run the container

Comment: @max To Build dockerfile (docker build -t test .)
To run dockerfile (docker run -d -p 80:80 test .)

Comment: @HansKilian Because when i do build Web Api without custom NuGet feed it do work

Comment: @HansKilian I am not saying it's because of NuGet Feed but that maybe an issue. Still need your assistance to verify the why i am getting this